# EMC test for device with WiFi module

Tags: noise, emc, wifi, transmitter

I want to test EMI radiated for a medical device with a WiFi module.

This medical device connects to a tablet  to perform its function. In the EMC chamber we have a lan and a USB connection outside the chamber. I think use a converter WiFi to LAN in chamber and out of chamber use a converter LAN to WiFi.

But I think this combination enters noise in to the chamber from the outside of the chamber.

Please guide me to how test this medical device.

Comment: Typically you use radio test modes, you don't actually talk wifi.  You need to discuss this with the wifi manufacturer and the testing lab.

Comment: Where are you located? What certification? Which Wifi band? EMC chambers can have ports with filtering, it really depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> But I think this combination enters noise in to the chamber from the outside of the chamber.

Yes

I dont know what your chamber looks like, but our chamber for example has shielded boxes buried into the floor, where you can place alien equipment which you need for the test, but not to have any influence to the test (in our case this often is a PLC).

So place your Lan 2 Wifi Converter in a shielded box and only feed-through the antenna with a short cable. This will minimize the influence.

If your chamber has no burried boxes you have two options I think: rent one which offers this Or place a shielded box with reflectors on the outside in your chamber and recalibrate the chamber with the box in it (but I doubt it conforms to standards then...)